# Ember.js How to bind isSelected class to the clicked view?

Tags: ember.js, view, binding

I have some views which will expand and show details when clicked.

For now, all the views can be clicked and expand, but the question is

**How to expand only the latest clicked view?**

For example, when I clicked view #1, it expand. So when I clicked view #2, the view #1 will collapse and view #2 expand etc.

I know we can bind a isSelected classname to the clicked view, but how do we tell the view to check *"If any other view is selected"* ?

Do we use `CollectionView` ? But how?

FYI this is the working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cebaba/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would change `view` to `component`. Although views have their valid use-cases, you are usually better off with a component.

Also, if you think about it, it makes sense that someone outside of the component would need to know which component was clicked last. That outside actor could be the controller, which could have a property called `lastComponentClicked` (which initially starts out as `null`)

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  lastClickedComponent: null
});
```

Then, you can pass that property into each component and the property becomes bound between the controller and all the components as in:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each content in model}}
      {{ x-box content=content lastClickedComponent=lastClickedComponent}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

So far, so good. Now, for the component itself:

```
App.XBoxComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['box'],
  isSelected: function(){
    return this.get('lastClickedComponent') === this._uuid;
  }.property('lastClickedComponent'),

  click: function(){
    this.set('lastClickedComponent', this._uuid);
  }  
});
```

Every time it is clicked, you can set a `lastClickedComponent` property, which is bound between ALL the components and the controller and thus will get reset every time. You can just set it to a value unique to the component, for example `this._uuid`.

`isSelected` computed property can then just check if `lastClickedComponent` property is that of THIS component, in which case the content you need to show will be expanded.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-box">
    {{content}}

    {{# if isSelected }}
      <div>LAST SELECTED</div>
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

Working solution [here](http://jsbin.com/pekosa/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks @Kalman, worked like a charm :D
But my _uuid is showing undefined, so I'm getting it's elementId instead.

Comment: Elementid is pretty unique aa well so u should be fine